# Remove 91 in customer telephone number from database table

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, mysql, query, database-update

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 . I have customer data for my site. **Previously I was collecting 12 digit telephone/mobile number while registration i.e. 91xxxxxxxxxx**

But because of some reason, from now, I will collect customer numbers only of **10 digits i.e. without 91**

So I want to **remove 91 from all customer's telephone number from database tables**

I do not have any idea where customer telephone numbers are present in Magento database tables

Comment: I'd not recommend doing it at the DB table, since you can easily mess up any other attributes. Try using Magento collections with some regexp for this.

Comment: No that is the requirement. I just only want to remove preceding 91 from numbers..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to knock up a quick script that iterates over all the records in the database and if the first two characters in the target column are 91 remove and update the record.

I was going to suggest a *dirty* SQL query but it wouldn't account for 91 being in the middle of the string.

You could also, do a NICER script that loads the customer collection and iterates, using the Magento models to handle the data replication to the right tables/columns

Comment: Thank  you for your answer but I do not know how many tables are there is Magento which contains customer telephone number!!

Comment: Iterate the customer model then! AKA neither do I know how many tables contain the number. In theory it _should_ just be the address tables

Comment: Sorry but I am a newbie in Magento.. What should I do by iterating custmoer model? and where?

Comment: If I get time later I'll see about writing up a WHOLE script for you

Comment: while I try to find some way.

Comment: In pseudo code its: Get ALL customers, Foreach customer, check all addresses the customer has, and test the phone number for starting with 91. If present change and save the customer.

Comment: Yes I got it what you want to say but my question is where should I write this? In custom module? Or where?

Comment: I'd do it in a dirty shell script myself. No need for a full module for this. Just boot Mage::app() and do the fixer

Comment: I searched my db.. Customer numbers are present in 'customer_address_entity_varchar' table.. I will remove 91 from there only..